# Добавить аргумент при запуске скрипта python

Tags: python

Хочу добавить строку как аргумент, но при обращении к этому элементу я вижу, что там хранится массив с 1-им значением. Как сделать, чтобы аргумент стал строкой?

```
parser.add_argument(
    help="Operator name",
    action="store",
    dest="operator",
    nargs="+"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nargs="+"` [отвечает](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) за объединение переданных аргументов в список. Укажите `nargs="?"` или совсем уберите, если вам не нужен.